# Creating Courses in classroom:Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: android, google-classroom

While creating course in google classroom api am getting an issue:

```
 { "code" : 403,
    "errors" : [ {
     "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
     "reason" : "forbidden"
     } ],
    "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
     "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
     }
```

my code:

```
 private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask {

        private com.google.api.services.classroom.Classroom mService = null;

        private Exception mLastError = null;

        MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {

            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new com.google.api.services.classroom.Classroom.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Classroom API Android Quickstart")
                    .build();
            Log.i("RR","mService"+mService);

        }

        /**
         * Background task to call Classroom API.
         *
         * @param params no parameters needed for this task.
         */
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            try {
                Course course = new Course()
                        .setName("10th Grade Biology")
                        .setSection("Period 2")
                        .setDescriptionHeading("Welcome to 10th Grade Biology")
                        .setDescription("We'll be learning about about the structure of living creatures "
                                + "from a combination of textbooks, guest lectures, and lab work. Expect "
                                + "to be excited!")
                        .setRoom("301")
                        .setOwnerId("Bio10")
                        .setCourseState("PROVISIONED");
                course = mService.courses().create(course).execute();
                System.out.printf("Course created: %s (%s)\n", course.getName(), course.getId());

           return course;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mLastError = e;
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }




        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mOutputText.setText("");
            mProgress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object data) {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (data == null ) {
                mOutputText.setText("No results returned.");
            } else {
               // data.add(0, "Data retrieved using the Classroom API:");
                mOutputText.setText(String.valueOf(data));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (mLastError != null) {
                if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                    showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                            ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                    .getConnectionStatusCode());
                } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                    startActivityForResult(
                            ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                            Sample1.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } else {
                    mOutputText.setText("The following error occurred:\n"
                            + mLastError.getMessage());
                    Log.i("RR","--"+mLastError.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                mOutputText.setText("Request cancelled.");
            }
        }

    }
```

I don't know what name should give to ownerid,whether this code correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not showing the code which could be the cause of your problem. It seems you are using a [courses.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/create) which require this scope:

> **Authorization Scopes** Requires the following OAuth scope:
>
> ```
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses
> ```

but instead you're using a :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly
```

Also, if you're changing scopes, delete the previously saved credentials.

Comment: Really thanks for your solution @noogul.I too changed that only then i got.you also said same thing.

Comment: How to use Oauth clientid using google classroom API in Android
@noogui

Comment: code is here https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/android

Comment: ,I already created auth client id and all,now the application working based on email ,i created oauth client id based on 1 email id,whenever am calling api its asking that email id its wrong way right,so we need to give id in coding itself instead of asking email

Comment: Try to open a new question in SO with regard to this. Someone with more experience might be able to help. Be sure to include the relevant code.